# Expression to use on array in ng-class

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

There's an array on my controller's `$scope` ...

```
$scope.myElements = [false, false, true, false, true, false];
```

... and the class on a div tag should be `firstClass` if at least one of the elements in said array is true, otherwise `secondClass`. Easy to achieve with `ng-class` ...

```
<div ng-class="anyElementTrue() ? 'firstClass' : 'secondClass'">
```

...and a helper function...

```
$scope.anyElementTrue = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.myElements.length; i++) {
        if ($scope.myElements[i]) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Is there an easier way to achieve the same just with an expression? Something like this:

```
<div ng-class="angular.any(myElements) ? 'firstClass' : 'secondClass'">
```

Except that [there is no `angular.any`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function). Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
<div ng-class="myElements.indexOf(true) > -1 ? 'firstClass' : 'secondClass'">
```